# How to dynamically build array key when dealing with a multiple <select> in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<select id = 'formMonths' multiple = 'multiple' name = 'formMonths[]'>
<option value="1">item1</option>
<option value="2">item2</option>
<option value="3">item3</option>
</select>
```

Then the array would look similar to below:

```
// assuming all elements were selected:
print_r($_REQUEST['formMonths']);

array
(
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
    2 => 3
)
```

The array will have keys starting at zero. How could you control what the keys are? So instead of starting at zero, they would start at one. And to take it a bit further, would it be possible to make the keys even more unique; so instead of a number have, persay, a date?

Comment: You could give your `<option>`s values like "2013-06-07 23:23" and then on submission use PHP's `strototime()` to convert it back to seconds, then do other `date()` stuff with it... I'm not sure what you want to do though.

Comment: But he's asking about the array keys, not the values...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays by definition start at zero. That's all there is to that. You could loop through and set each array index x number of indeces further back in the array but why you would want to do that is beyond me.
A little more info on your end goal would help us give you a better solution.

As far as setting your own keys, you're talking about an associative array, and that is possible:

```
$newArr = array();
for($i = 0; i < count($_REQUEST['formMonths']); $i++){
    $newIndex = //some code to generate whatever index you want as a string
    newArr[$newIndex] = $_REQUEST['formMonths'][$i];
}
```

Which you now access each index by name:

```
//Example using an index you know you set "october10":
$somevar = newArr["october10"];
```